# Bash: process substitution and stdin

Tags: bash, stdin, process-substitution

The following line is obvious:

```
echo "bla" | foo | bar
```

But does the ones below do the same?

```
echo "bla" | bar <(foo)
echo "bla" | bar < <(foo)
```

Which of the `foo` and `bar` read "bla" from stdin and why?

I mean that, of course, I can just code it and check it, but I'm not sure if it's defined behavior or I'm exploiting features I should not rely on.

Answer (score 9):

That's shell dependant and not documented AFAICS. In `ksh` and `bash`, in the first case, `foo` will share the same stdin as `bar`. They will fight for the output of `echo`.

So for instance in,

```
$ seq 10000 | paste - <(tr 1 X)'
1       X
2       X042
3       X043
4       X044
5       X045
[...]
```

You see evidence that `paste` reads every other block of text from `seq`'s output while `tr` reads the other ones.

With `zsh`, it gets the outer stdin (unless it's a terminal and the shell is not interactive in which case it's redirected from `/dev/null` like in `cmd &`). `ksh` (where it originated), `zsh` and `bash` are the only Bourne-like shells with support for process substitution AFAIK.

In `echo "bla" | bar < <(foo)`, note that `bar`'s stdin will be the pipe fed by the output of `foo`. That's well defined behaviour. In that case, it appears that `foo`'s stdin is the pipe fed by `echo` in all of `ksh`, `zsh` and `bash`.

If you want to have a consistent behaviour across all three shells and be future-proof since the behaviour might change as it's not documented, I'd write it:

```
echo bla | { bar <(foo); }
```

To be sure `foo`'s stdin is also the pipe from `echo` (I can't see why you'd want to do that though). Or:

```
echo bla | bar <(foo < /dev/null)
```

To make sure `foo` does **not** read from the pipe from `echo`. Or:

```
{ echo bla | bar 3<&- <(foo <&3); } 3<&0
```

To have `foo`'s stdin the outer stdin like in current versions of `zsh`.

Comment: "In that case, foo's stdin is the pipe fed by echo in all of ksh, zsh and bash." You've tested this by hand just now, or is it somewhere documented?

Comment: Does "in the first case" in the first line refer to ` | foo | bar` or ` | bar <(foo)`?

Answer (score 4):

`echo "bla" | foo | bar`: The output of `echo "bla"` is redirected to `foo`, whose output is redirected to `bar`.

`echo "bla" | bar <(foo)`: That one pipes the output of `echo "bla"` to `bar`. But `bar` is executed with an argument. The argument is the path to the file descritor, where the output of `foo` will be sent to. This argument behaves like a file that contains the output of `foo`. So, **that's not the same.**

`echo "bla" | bar < <(foo)`: One may assume that the output of `echo "bla"` should be sent to `bar` and the whole statement is equivalent to the first one. But, that's not correct. The following happens: *Because the input redirection `<` is performed after the pipe (`|`), it overwrites it*. So `echo "bla"` is not piped to bar. Instead the output of `foo` is redirected as standard input to `bar`. To clear this out see the following command and output:

```
$ echo "bla" | cat < <(echo "foo")
foo
```

As you see `echo "bla"` is superseded by `echo "foo"`.

Now see this command:

```
$ echo "bar" | cat < <(awk '{printf "%s and foo", $0}')
bar and foo
```

So `echo "bar"` is piped to `awk`, which reads stdin and adds the string `and foo` to the output. This output is piped to `cat`.

Comment: And my question is: "Is the fact that `awk` reads "bar" a defined behavior?"

Comment: Yes, it is. `cmd1 < <(cmd2)` behaves the same as `cmd2 | cmd1`.

Comment: Or `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3` is the same as `cmd1 | cmd3 < <(cmd2)`

Comment: If it was wikipedia I'd put "citation needed" tag on your statements :) The whole point of my question is that it works as you say, but I couldn't find any documentation about it.