# Command to verify CRC (CRC32) hashes recursively

Tags: zip, hashsum, checksum, 7z

With the commands `md5sum`, `sha1sum`, `sha256sum` I can take a text file having an hash and a path per line and verify the entire list of files in a single command, like `sha1sum -c mydir.txt`. (Said text file is easy to produce with a loop in `find` or other.)

Is there a way to do the same with a list of CRC/CRC32 hashes?

Such hashes are often stored inside zip-like archives, like ZIP itself or 7z. For instance:

```
$ unzip -v archive.zip 
Archive:  archive.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
 8617812  Stored  8617812   0% 12-03-2015 15:20 13fda20b  0001.tif
```

Or:

```
$ 7z l -slt archive.7z

Path = filename
Size = 8548096
Packed Size =
Modified = 2015-12-03 14:20:20
Attributes = A_ -rw-r--r--
CRC = B2F761E3
Encrypted = -
Method = LZMA2:24
Block = 0
```

Comment: Cf. https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/2254ac12/#eb85/da83/64bc

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of  http://askubuntu.com/q/303662/395065

Comment: It's unlikely that there'll be a command to verify CRC hashes recursively. What would be more usual is for two or more commands to be combined to deliver the target requirement. There'll be answers to "How do I run a command recursively", and "How do I extract a particular value from a list", I'm sure.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the question. Here we are looking at a specific feature of the various hashing options. `7z h` is a recent example of tool for recursive hashing in CRC32 and more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Try RHash

Try [RHash](http://rhash.sourceforge.net/).

There are packages for
[Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/rhash.html), [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/rhash).

## Example

```bash
$ echo -n a > a.txt; echo -n b > b.txt; echo -n c > c.txt
✔

$ rhash --crc32 --simple *.txt > checksums.crc32
✔

$ cat checksums.crc32
e8b7be43  a.txt
71beeff9  b.txt
06b9df6f  c.txt
✔

$ rhash --crc32 --check checksums.crc32
--( Verifying checksums.crc32 )-------------------------------------------------
a.txt                                               OK
b.txt                                               OK
c.txt                                               OK
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Everything OK
✔
```

### Note 1: --simple format

If you don't use the `--simple` formatting option then rhash will default to a different format. And this may not be what you want:

```bash
$ rhash --crc32 *.txt
; Generated by RHash v1.3.7 on 2020-06-03 at 16:02.51
; Written by Kravchenko Aleksey (Akademgorodok) - http://rhash.sf.net/
;
;            1  15:58.36 2020-06-03 a.txt
;            1  15:58.36 2020-06-03 b.txt
;            1  15:58.36 2020-06-03 c.txt
a.txt E8B7BE43
b.txt 71BEEFF9
c.txt 06B9DF6F
✔
```

### Note 2: --all option

If you wanna go crazy: try the [`--all` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590653/92802) to get ALL supported hashes at once.

Comment: Excellent! It's packaged in Fedora too. I switched the accepted answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

The `crc32` utility does not have an option like `-c` of the `sha1sum`. Nevertheless the verification can be done in a script.

Let say we have stored crc32 values in file in the same format like sha1sum prints values:

```
a8374911 *file1.ext
32c5188e *file2
6592d5e5 *bflmpsvz
```

The crc32 can be checked via bash script:

```
while read line
do 
   name=${line#* \*}
   crc32=`crc32 "$name"`
   echo -n "$name: "
   if [ "${line% \**}" == "$crc32" ]
   then
      echo OK
   else
      echo FAILED
   fi
done < file_with_crc32
```

The script provides the same output as `sha1sum -c`. It iterates over all lines in the file `file_with_crc32` and for each line

- retrieves the filename from read line
- calculates crc32
- compares the calculated value with the value from file
- prints the result